# Why Qualys SSL Server Test is giving me 80 and not 100 in Key Exchange?

Tags: tls, key-exchange, defense

My `openssl ciphers -v 'CIPHER'` output is the following:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
```

I think that my server meet all theirs Key Exchange requirements to get a 100 [SSL Server Rating Guide](https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_Server_Rating_Guide_2009d.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the DH parameters used for your DHE cipher suites use a 1024-bit modulus.

(I must say that this "scoring" is completely arbitrary and not very rational; awarding 128-bit symmetric keys a grade lower than the one for 256-bit symmetric keys makes sense only if 128-bit keys can be considered somehow "breakable" in the foreseeable future, which is a rather preposterous assertion.)

Comment: Thanks Tom. Could you pls point me out to how change such parameter? so I can execute again the test and get 100. I'm using Apache 2.2 and openssl 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I share you criteria about key length, but result that lot of manager are taking that test result as a evaluation criteria of server setup security, so... my server must past it ;)

Comment: @gsc-frank not even gmail/google get 100 across the board... https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=gmail.com&s=74.125.227.245

Comment: Yes, but they must balance the performance impact and client access vs security, in my case security is paramount ;) BTW, gmail got a 90 in key exchange ;)

Comment: @gsc-frank: apparently, since version 2.5.0-dev of `mod_ssl` (from 5 days ago !), you can put custom DH parameters in the same file as the certificate; see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile). Note that there may be interoperability issues... and you won't get this with the stock Apache 2.2 from Ubuntu. Though I guess you could get the package source, patch it to use a bigger modulus, and recompile it. A simpler method would be to use only ECDHE cipher suites, but this may reject too many existing Web browsers for your taste.

Comment: @TomLeek Thanks a lot! I will move to Apache 2.4 and then use only ECDHE ciphers to get a 4 x 100 score. Seem to me that still remain some time to such new `mod_ssl` option arrive to Ubuntu. Your help was very important, thanks again.

Comment: BTW, your guess was correct, I remove the DH cipher and got a 4 x 100 score on the test ;)